# How to create a function to map the JSON response to a list of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jsonnode

I getting the response from the API

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Weekly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-05-19",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Weekly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2021-05-19": {
            "1. open": "144.4400",
            "2. high": "145.8000",
            "3. low": "140.9200",
            "4. close": "143.1900",
            "5. adjusted close": "143.1900",
            "6. volume": "12399954",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
        "2021-05-14": {
            "1. open": "145.8000",
            "2. high": "148.3800",
            "3. low": "141.1400",
            "4. close": "144.6800",
            "5. adjusted close": "144.6800",
            "6. volume": "27415665",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
```

I want to map the JSON response of the Weekly time series.
in such a way that I have a list of objects where date is the ID and the open, close, etc are the object data variables.

This is to be done in spring boot

Kindly help on this

I have searched everwhere on how this can be done.
The closest I have come is using JsonNode

```
@GetMapping("/tryObject")
public WeeklyTimeSeries getWeeklyTimeSeries() throws IOException
{
    String uri ="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    WeeklyTimeSeries result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, WeeklyTimeSeries.class);
    String strResult = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        weekService.getJsonObjects(strResult);
    return result;
}
```

The weekService is as :

```
@Service
@Component
public class weeklyTimeService {
  public void getJsonObjects(String result) throws IOException
    {
        JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(result);
        weekReport report = new weekReport();

        System.out.println(jsonNode);
    }
}
```

However this only gives response for the Weekly Adjusted Time Series and not map the JSON to objects

In other examples , i find the data is extracted from JSON by using a tag . However , here the tag is the date which may not be fixed.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you post what you tried?

Comment: You should put the code you tried first and then you ask. This will help you more as trying yourself helps more in developing your skills. Also, it will make you avoid the easy way out and give more understanding of the logic behind what you have.